# Como puedo referenciar una columna de una tabla es SQL usando una variable?

Tags: sql

Como puedo referenciar una columna en SQL usando una variable.

Ejemplo ..........

```
Declare @nombrecolumna varchar(50) 
Set @nombrecolumna = 'fecha' 

Select  @nombrecolumna from columnas
```

Answer (score 1):

Antes que nada, esto es una mala idea. SQL no se debería usar así.

Aquí hay un artículo en inglés sobre los peligros del SQL dinámico: https://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

De todos modos si realmente quieres puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
DECLARE @nombreColumna VARCHAR(50)
SET @nombreColumna = 'fecha'
SET @query = 'select ' + @nombrecolumna + ' from tableA'
EXEC sp_executesql @query
```